# Recursive functions. Calculate the definite integral using the Newton-Leibniz formula. C++

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, math, integral

Given: two real numbers *a, b (a < b)* and a positive integer

*n*. Calculate the definite integral using the Newton-Leibniz formula:
[a(top) ∫ b(bottom) (f(x,n)dx = F(b,n)-F(a,n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qnjn.png) 
where F(x,n) is the first-order *(antiderivative, inverse derivative, primitive function, primitive integral)* function f(x,n):
[F(x, n) = integral(f(x,n)dx)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRXaK.png)

Implement the calculation of F(x,n) in two ways:

1. as a recursive.
2. as a nonrecursive function.

That's what needs to solve. Click on the link to open the photo.

[F(x,n) = ∫(ctg^n*xdx)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrunT.png)

I solved this problem using the *pow* function. My teacher asks me to solve this problem without using the *pow* function. Help me with the solution without using the *pow* function.

Recursion solution

```
// Recursion
double F(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return x;
    else if (n == 1)
        return log(fabs(sin(x))); 
    else
        return -pow(cos(x) / sin(x), n - 1) / (n - 1) - F(x, n - 2);
}
```

Solving with a loop

```
// For loop
double F_for(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return x;
    else if (n == 1)
        return log(fabs(sin(x))); 
    else
    {
        double F1 = x;
        double F2 = log(fabs(sin(x)));
        double res = 0.0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            res = -pow(cos(x) / sin(x), i - 1) / (i - 1) - F1;
            F1 = F2;
            F2 = res;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

main function

```
int main()
{
    double a, b;

    cout << "Enter a: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter b: ";
    cin >> b;

    int n;

    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Recursion: " << F(b, n) - F(a, n) << std::endl;

    cout << "A loop: " << F_for(b, n) - F_for(a, n);

    return 0;
}
```

P.S.
Help me solve it without using the pow function, please.
I already wrote my function "my_power".

My instructor said: "You can't use a power function, neither the standard one (pow) nor your own (power). The reason is that any use of such functions leads to a loop, and your loop, or the one in the standard function, are details. A recursive function is itself a loop; using a variable-increment results in a loop - that's not efficient."

```
double power(double x, int y)
{
    double temp;
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;
    temp = power(x, y / 2);
    if ((y % 2) == 0) {
        return temp * temp;
    }
    else {
        if (y > 0)
            return x * temp * temp;
        else
            return (temp * temp) / x;
    }
}

I also tested this function


void test_my_power()
{
    cout << "pow" << pow(2, -3) << "0" << endl;
    cout << "power" << power(2, -3) << "0" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "pow" << pow(0, -3) << "0" << endl;
    cout << "power" << power(0, -3) << "0" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "pow" << pow(0, 1) << "0" << endl;
    cout << "power" << power(0, 1) << "0" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "pow" << pow(0, -1) << "0" << endl;
    cout << "power" << power(0, -1) << "0" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "pow" << pow(8, 4) << "0" << endl;
    cout << "power" << power(8, 4) << "0" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "pow" << pow(11, 3) << "0" << endl;
    cout << "power" << power(11, 3) << "0" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "pow" << pow(5, 6) << "0" << endl;
    cout << "power" << power(5, 6) << "0" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your teacher probably wants you to develop your skills by going through the thinking process of finding the solution. It should generally not be difficult to get rid of the `pow` function for integer exponents. Think about (1) what is the result of the `pow()` function in the first iteration (2) how is the result of the `pow()` function in one iteration related to the result in the previous iteration.

Comment: For the recursive approach I recommend to use your own `double my_power_function(double base, int n)` function. For the loop approach you need 2 temporary variables `double tmp = sin(x)/cos(x); double tmp1 = tmp;`, use `tmp` instead of `pow(....)` and as a last instruction in the loop do `tmp *= tmp1;`.

Comment: If you expand a few steps of the recursive definition you will find a pattern.

Comment: To some of the commenters: From the Stackoverflow "tour pages" https://stackoverflow.com/tour :  Ask questions, get answers, **no distractions**. This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no **chit-chat**.

Comment: [@mch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3684343/mch),
I already wrote my function "my_power". He said "You can't use it either.". Write without "pow" function. 
P.S. I added the code above.

Comment: It's unclear and ambiguous what OP wants.

Comment: @madhur4127 It's full comment from instructor "You can't use a power function, neither the standard one (pow) nor your own (power). The reason is that any use of such functions leads to a loop, and your loop, or the one in the standard function, are details. A recursive function is itself a loop; using a variable-increment results in a loop - that's not efficient."

Comment: Preventing usage of any loop / recursion makes me think your teacher wants you to use maths to reduce the summation to a single formula.

Comment: @Kaisar That comment doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher probably wants you to compute `pow` on the fly as you iterate the loop.

This code:

```cpp
const auto t = cos(x) / sin(x);

for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
   const auto val = pow(t, i - 1);
   ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```cpp
auto power = t;

for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
   const auto val = power;
   ...
   power *= t;
}
```

and doesn't use `pow`.

Comment: He said: " you cannot use the "pow" function directly or indirectly". Need to solve without pow. I need to change this part of the code: return -pow(cos(x) / sin(x), n - 1) / (n - 1) - F(x, n - 2);

Comment: @Kaisar The second loop doesn't use a power function in any way.

Comment: @molbdnilo It user loop, but I need a recursion! here's full comment from instuctor: "You can't use a power function, neither the standard one (pow) nor your own (power). The reason is that any use of such functions leads to a loop, and your loop, or the one in the standard function, are details. A recursive function is itself a loop; using a variable-increment results in a loop - that's not efficient."

Comment: I need a recursion not a loop.

Comment: You also need a loop version without the power function. You can use a similar approach with recursion if you write a helper function that passes the powers of cot(x) "upwards" through a reference argument.

Comment: @molbdnilo , ok how to rewrite this without "pow" and without a loop? and without a variable that compute a power? "-pow(cos(x) / sin(x), n - 1) / (n - 1) - F(x, n - 2);"

Comment: If you know that the recursion is going to use `pow(cos(x) / sin(x), n - 3)`, it can store it in a reference and you can say something like `double y = Fhelper(x, n-2, pwr); pwr *= cot(x)*cot(x);return -pwr/(n-1)-y;`. Set up the appropriate base case and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @molbdnilo this will be more inefficient than a raw loop lol. That's not what OP wants?

Comment: @madhur4127 The task is to write one iterative and one recursive version.